# What is the most efficient way of updating the UI from a service

Tags: android, service

My app needs to update the UI every 10 seconds from a service
It just updates a text box, thats it
I have read that there a number of ways to achieve this, using:
handlers
broadcasts
extending the application class

can you tell me which is the most efficient for this case and why.
thanks you

Comment: There are lots of ways of doing this, can you tell us what you've tried? Can you give a better description of what exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the broadcast receiver/intent system, especially as it will be easy to bundle the text with the intent. Just get the service to put the text into the intent, then fire it off and have a broadcast receiver on the application pick it up and send the text to the UI thread for updating.

Note: make sure to turn the service off or make it stop polling data/sending intents when the application is backgrounded or dead as it will not be needed.